# how to insert a date stamp into a table when a row is added automatically

Tags: excel, vba

I am wanting to update a table we have for outstanding issue in one of our projects so the date of issue being raised field is prepopulated when a new row is inserted in the table. the reason for doing this is I'm aware users occasionally will miss this field when adding data to the table and when going back it is hard to remember when you you raised the issue in the first place.

VBA is not my strong suit but I understand just about enough to get by and know the code I need for inserting the timestamp into a cell and just need to work out how to direct it to the right part of the table but that shouldn't just need to point it to the last row of the table and the column can be feed by its header.

What I'm more stuck on is how I get this done without having the user notice so no need for a macro button to add rows etc. I believe this should be doable using the change event handler but I just don't know enough about how I'd set this up. any advice would be appreciated

if you require any sample code I'm working or a mock up of the table let me know and i'll pull something together.

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks for the feed back, regarding the initial code the time stamp code I'm using is a simple ` value=now.numbwerformat="dd/mm/yyyy"` whilst the aim would be to have the change event check when a new row on a table is created on for sake of argument table1 add the above code output to the new row in the "date raised" column (can't remember of the top of my head how I type that portion of the code out but can work on it and get back to you if you prefer.

Comment: I only said that the event is triggered only if you **insert** a row. In a table, or in the sheet, but not when added a row after to the table bottom one. This is not a change for VBA. And saying how the time stamp should look, you did not answer my clarification question: **where to be placed the necessary time stamp, with reference to the table itself**. Then, you are still not able to show us a piece of code and I cannot help you, anymore...

Comment: your right that a change event is triggered by any change element and does need an intersect check before proccing. but would i whilst you say adding in data underneath dosen't count as excel auto corrects this new data to be part of the table (if using the next row in the sheet) surrely at the point of row creation it would intersect the table columns so should count. i've tried entering in the code again although i have never gotten stacks or reddit markdown to work as intended for me.

` dim ts as date

Comment: If you have only the table in discussion in the sheet, the `Intersect` may not be necessary. Otherwise it is. About the last row, **it is not a matter of intersection or not**. It is a matter of  not  being triggered by the event.

Comment: for the sheet in question yes it is only the table on that sheet all the lookups and supporting stuff is on separate sheets this table is just meant to give an overview of the issues that come up in the project over time.  whilst i am likely to rember to press a macro butto or go into the sub menu to enter it another user is not so i need to have this date stamp which currently would go into col 8 of the new row in the table (but i'd prefer to link to the header name in case stuff gets inserted) to be seamless without the user knowing hence trying an event trigger which i'm not strong about